# -webkit-box-orient and --webkit-box-flex browser competability

Tags: css, html, web, webkit, cross-browser

I have a cross-browser compatability issue and I am trying to look for a solution for IE9/IE10 and Firefox.

```
nav {
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
}
nav a {
    -webkit-box-flex:1;
}
```

The code above only seems to work in Chrome. Does Mozilla have a browser specific code for this? Does IE have a browser specific code for this?

The website this code is from is http://www.daven.nl/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

IE9 does not support flexbox at all.  There are basically 3 different specs that have been implemented by the different browser vendors.

- September 2012 Candidate Recommendation (http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-css3-flexbox-20120918/)
- March 2012 Working Draft (http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-flexbox-20120322/)
- July 2009 Working Draft (http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-css3-flexbox-20090723/)

Starting with Firefox 20, you'll only need to care about the specs from 2012:  IE10 follows the one from March and everyone else follows the one from September.  If you're wanting to support browsers following the 2009 draft, be aware that Mozilla doesn't support `flex-wrap`.  I know this was still a complaint in the recent Firefox versions that had experimental support (disabled by default) for the new draft.  Not sure if that is supposed to be fixed in version 20.

I've written a collection of mixins in Sass (depends on 2 Compass mixins) that will cover all of the specs.  There's comments showing which properties or values don't exist for a given draft.

https://gist.github.com/4461470

Comment: They're basically a function containing reusable CSS.  See:  http://sass-lang.com/.  You don't have to use Sass, but this is probably the only document out there at the moment that matches up each property/value from each of the drafts.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox uses -moz and IE uses -ms for its vendor prefix. However -ms is not supported in most versions I believe IE 10 is the only one that supports -ms.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-orient.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-flex.asp

```
 /* Firefox */
 display:-moz-box;
 -moz-box-orient:horizontal;

-moz-box-flex:2.0;
```

I would try this in IE 10 and see if it works. According to w3 it doesn't look like it has much support in IE. But it is worth a try.

```
 display:-ms-box;
 -ms-box-orient:horizontal;

-ms-box-flex:2.0;
```

Comment: I have implemented both firefox and IE10 versions of the same code aswell as the W3C specific standard. But it seems that it just won't do what is intended in firefox and IE9. (Havn't tested IE10 as I don't have it on this workstation. Cannot download here due to the policy. Will have to wait until the company updates.)

Comment: Yeah that seems right. I doubt you will have any luck getting it to work with IE9 and below. Unfortunately IE 9 and below doesn't fully support CSS3 attributes. 9 Supports quite a few, 8 and below support very few if any.

Answer (score 0):

I try this on IE10, and it seems to be fine.

```
-ms-flex:1 0 auto;
```